# enable tab from single drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox

I have `3 tabs` and `1 combo box` in a jsp page. By default `Tab 1 is enabled and tab2 and tab3 are in disabled mode` ,  When i will select `term one`(in drop down item) then automatically i am going to `1st tab` and if `please select option` is choosen then `tab2 and tab3 will be disabled`

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AavsW/21/

but what i want is if i will select `term one`(in drop down item) then i want to go to `tab3` that is order of tabs and drop down items need not to be in the same way. Should i use `data-tabid=""?` How can i implement it? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Currently the code uses the `value` from the `option` - just change the value to match the tab you want to open when the option is selected ...

Comment: please be specific about your requirement.. cant figure out your problem.

Comment: @ManseUK can you please add something more, `value="1"` like this?

Comment: @PareshBalar if i will select `term one from drop down` then i want to move to `tab 3` not to `tab 2` as currently going

Comment: @Tom added an answer - im sure im missing something though ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite difficult to know exactly what your want because your question is difficult to read and understand... but you can easily change which tab is selected on change of the selection option ... your current HTML is this :

```
<select name="porting-p1" class="dropdown">
   <option value="1" class="disablenext">Please select an option...</option>
   <option value="2" class="enablenext">TERMS 1</option>
   <option value="3" class="enablenext">TERMS 2</option>
</select>
```

And your jQuery `onchange` function does this :

```
// enable tab
$('#wizard').tabs('enable', $('.dropdown').val());
// select tab
$('#wizard').tabs('select', $('.dropdown').val());
```

what this does is take the `value` from your `option` and enable and select the matching tab ... so to change the order just change the value in your HTML :

```
<select name="porting-p1" class="dropdown">
   <option value="1" class="disablenext">Please select an option...</option>
   <option value="3" class="enablenext">TERMS 1</option>
   <option value="2" class="enablenext">TERMS 2</option>
</select>
```

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/AavsW/30/)

You will notice here that if you select `TERMS 1` you will go to tab `3` as the value specified in the `option` for `TERMS 1` is `3` ....

Answer (score 1):

Yes you dhould do something like that.

```
<div id="tab1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="terms" data-tabid="2" /> Terms 1<br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="terms" data-tabid="1" /> Terms 2
</div>
```

In this way you go to tab 3 when you select term 1 and to tab 2 when you select term 2

Comment: thanks Nicola but i want this same to be done in drop down menus, i have edited and have written `term one in drop down item`